# Calculate time difference between multiple records in a day using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to ask you for your help to create a query that will let me do the following:

I have an online shop, and I have a database where I store the products each user has viewed with a timestamp. I want to visualize 'product sessions', what I mean by this is to obtain the time the user spent watching products divided by day (and also how many products were viewed during this day). 

An example:

*My recently viewed table with user ID*

[image: My recently viewed items]

I want to create a query that will give me this output

```
|   DAY    |    TIME  | PRODUCTS |
----------------------------------
|2018-07-31| 00:00:04 |    2     |
----------------------------------
|2018-08-01| 02:38:56 |    5     |
```

So far I was only able to do this:

```
SELECT DATE(`added_timestamp`) AS day, COUNT(*) AS num_products
FROM tb_recently_viewed 
WHERE `user_id`= 'bac240e3eefbb7dff0bc03d00f392f0d'
GROUP BY DATE(`added_timestamp`)
ORDER BY day
```

Which outputs the products seen in a day:

[image]

Any help would be appreciate it.

Comment: You will want to do this as a subquery to find max and min time (by userid and day) and join that to what you have here.  Though the logic here seems a bit messed as there really isnt a session.  If i was a midnight shopper and was on your site at 00:01am and i went to bed...then at 8pm the next day i log and look at another product, do you really want to see 19:59 as the time entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
select
    date(added_timestamp) as day,
    count(*) as num_products,
    timediff(max(time(added_timestamp)), min(time(added_timestamp))) as time_diff
  from tb_recently_viewed
  group by date(added_timestamp)
```

Result:

```
day         num_products  time_diff
----------  ------------  ---------
2018-07-31  2             00:00:04                 
2018-08-01  2             02:38:56
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed!